# Copy Values from One Column to Another in Google Scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a data table that pulls its information from a series of VLOOKUPs in google sheets. I am constantly editing the source which changes my data table. I need a google scripts code that would copy the cells that have been affected by the formulas to another column that would not be affected. I tried copying everything at once to move over but the second time it was activated, the now blank cells overwrote the formerly I was able to successfully do this task with VBA, but I cannot figure out the transition. Here is it what I have so far:

```
function CopyCells() {

var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Records');
var loc = sheet2.getRange("C2:C126").getValues();
var taget_sheet = sheet2.getRange("D2:D126");
for(i = 1;i == "Present";i++){ i.copyTo("target_sheet")}       
}
```

My VBA Code:

```
 Dim ColERange As Range
 Dim ColFRange As Range 
 Set ColERange = Range("E1:E100") 
 Set ColFRange = Range("F1:F100") 
 Dim Cell As Range 
 For Each Cell In ColERange 
   If Cell.Value = "Present" 
     Then Cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = Cell.Value 
   ElseIf Cell.Value = "Absent" 
     Then Cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = Cell.Value 
   ElseIf Cell.Value = "" 
     Then Cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = Cell.Value 
   End If 
 Next Cell
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
/*
 Dim ColERange As Range
 Dim ColFRange As Range 
 Set ColERange = Range("E1:E100") 
 Set ColFRange = Range("F1:F100") 
 Dim Cell As Range 
 For Each Cell In ColERange 
   If Cell.Value = "Present" 
     Then Cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = Cell.Value 
   ElseIf Cell.Value = "Absent" 
     Then Cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = Cell.Value 
   ElseIf Cell.Value = "" 
     Then Cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = Cell.Value 
   End If 
 Next Cell   
*/
```

I think this version is what you want because by just changing one thing you can change the column you copying to..

```
function CopyCells1(col) {
  var col=col || 1;
  var sh=SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Records');
  var rg1=sh.getRange("C2:C126");
  var vA=rg1.getValues();
  var rg2=rg1.offset(0, col);//Changing the column offset allows you to gain access to the other columns. Note: it can be negative.
  var vB=rg2.getValues();
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++){
    if((vA[i][0]=='Present')||(vA[i][0]=='Absent')){
      vA[i][0]=vB[i][0];
    }
  }
  rg2.setValues(vB);
}
```

Comment: Cooper, thanks for the quick response! Unfortunately, I'm still having the same problem. When I did this on Excel, I remember that I had to do a for loop with an if condition of whether or not the cell contained a value, and then, resulting in the copy to if cell was not blank. Any suggestions on how to translate from VBA to GAS?

Comment: Can you Show me your VBA?

Comment: Dim ColERange As Range
Dim ColFRange As Range
Set ColERange = Range("E1:E100")
Set ColFRange = Range("F1:F100")
Dim Cell As Range

For Each Cell In ColERange
    If Cell.Value = "Present" Then
        Cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = Cell.Value
    ElseIf Cell.Value = "Absent" Then
        Cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = Cell.Value
    ElseIf Cell.Value = "" Then
        Cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = Cell.Value
    End If
    Next Cell

Comment: For some reason, it will not let me paste it in code format but this is the part that I'm trying to translate.

Comment: Can you share a public link to your spreadsheet.  Remove private information.

Comment: Yes, but give me a couple minutes to do that. This sheet is very complex.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sUFALS740w4HquxPYMJLLH6eIuSTj-bhBcLKembgK14/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Go ahead and try the code.  I didn't use the offset method but I could have.

Comment: The new one only puts Column C's results into the first four cells in Column D.

Comment: I just ran it in your spreadsheet and it works okay as far a I can tell.  If you don't agree then please tell me what else is required.

Comment: Unfortunately, the new one does not copy at all. I'm personally a VBA guy so I could not tell you the problem.

Comment: I just ran it on the sample spreadsheet.  You can run it from the menu I created on your example. It runs. It copies data from Column C to Column D